# How to find which port number the jar is running in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, gcloud

How to find which port number the jar is running in google cloud VIrtual machine ?

Comment: What do you run? what's your configuration?

Answer (score 2):

To list all services listening on TCP ports, run this command:

```
sudo netstat -tunlp
```

Within that list, you will find any Java processes that are in the listening state.

Comment: Or `sudo netstat -tunlp | grep java` for a compact response.

Comment: Or, since `netstat` is [deprecated](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ss-command), you can use `ss -tunlp` (same flags as `netstat` to ease migration) or its more descriptive equivalent `ss --tcp --udp --numeric --listening --processes`